How can I get the camera tracker from https://github.com/dwalton76/rubiks-cube-tracker to work?
so I tried to install the tracker onto my raspberry pi as directed. My first issue was external environment thingy when downloading via pip. So I attempted to do so in a virtual environment, which resulted in an error which said "required file not found". Therefore, for my last attempt, I tried to run the make init file after git cloning it. The error here was that I needed to login to https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8 for some reason for the make file to be happy. I would very much like this to work on my system if possible. If anyone can help, that would be amazing! (Secondly, I am quite new into this new area of "working with code" as opposed to just writing a python script and simply executing it, therefore, if possible, could you explain why some things work?)
Regards and thanks!,
J

initially tried to download and run directly explained in readme
Then, (due to the issue) tried to run it in a virtual environment
Then, tried to run the make init file leading to a wierd login error
My last option I could try (but I don't want to because I don't quite nescecarily know what I am doing,) is to bypass the pi's restrictions and do option one again.

please help!,
Regards
